# React native - How to save image with filename using Camera Roll and RNFS

Tags: react-native

I have a function that saves the image from device using `RNFS` and `CameraRoll` . It works perfectly on android devices however in iOS devices it only saves the image in the album without renaming.

Here's my function

```
const handleSaveImageToDevice = async () => {
    try {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        const granted = await androidPermission();
        if (!granted) {
          Linking.openSettings();
          return;
        }
      }

      viewShotRef?.current?.capture().then((data) => {
        RNFS.writeFile(
          RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + `image-${randomNumber}`,
          data,
          'base64',
        ).then((success) => {
          return CameraRoll.save(
            RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + `image-${randomNumber}`,
            {
              type: 'photo',
              album: 'Sample Album',
            },
          );
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  };
```

What I wanted to happen is when I save the image in iOS it will be named as `image-1.jpg`

Also take note that I didn't get an error when i try to `console.log(e)` in the catch block.

Answer (score -1):

I'd confirm if `CachesDirectoryPath` exists in iOS.  From what I can recall, I think for iOS there is another path you must save it as the `CachesDirectoryPath` does not exist.

Personally, I'll save the files to `DocumentDirectoryPath` as this path exists on both platforms.

Comment: I tried to change this, same implementation in my code above from `CachesDirectoryPath` to `DocumentDirectoryPath` but still doesn't rename the file.

Comment: If this is on a emulator on iOS, try a physical device if possible.

Comment: Yes, I only tried it on iOS emulator. My code is just the same in the given example I just changed `CachesDirectoryPath` into `DocumentDirectoryPath`

Comment: I'd confirm that directory is available on the emulator.

Comment: I tried it in physical devices, but still remains the same. Can you paste your sample implementation.